# Unexplained behavior of the INTERSECT clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables, with similar content.

If I use the INTERSECT function then I get 5000 of 5005. But, if I try to find the 5 difference with the EXCEPT function like this:

```
Table1 
EXCEPT
Table2
```

Or with

```
Table2 
EXCEPT 
Table1
```

Then I get no results. Meaning no difference. Where does the 5 in the INTERSECT clause come from?

Comment: sample data will help us to help you

Comment: Cant deliver. To big.

Comment: I suspect you have bags rather than sets (I.e. multiple rows with identical values in all columns). Since these are set operators, they return sets with no duplicates.

Comment: This is why it's called **sample** data, @Petersselorse . We aren't asking for your *entire* dataset, just a sample that demonstrates the same behaviour.

Comment: As noted [Duplicates in one table would explain this](https://dbfiddle.uk/TQ5lOyiw)

Comment: To demonstrate @Damien_The_Unbeliever 's comment: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/MffQ9yze)

Comment: There's a 90% chance in constructing the sample data that reproduces the issue that you will answer the question for yourself anyway. As highly likely you are seeing this due to duplicates being removed by the `DISTINCT`-ifying nature of `INTERSECT`

Comment: You saying on table could have duplicated rows.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

Answer (score -1):

One Table had duplicate rows (entire row) that was the cause. Interesting.

No `EXCEPT` and still difference `INTERSECT` means, duplicates possible.

Comment: *"No expect and still difference intersect means, duplicates possible."* What does this mean?